# End-to-end machine learning project processes

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, end-to-end, flowchart

I've read a book chapter that walks you through all the steps involved in an end-to-end machine learning project. After doing all the practical exercises I'm still not quite sure that my way of thinking about the whole process is right.

I've tried to depict it in the following flowchart:

[image: end-to-end machine learning project flowchart]

Is this the right way of thinking about all the steps in an ML project? Is something missing?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1):

Seems decent.

Just want to mention that the cross-validation and model-selection in your short-listing step could also include tuning the pipelines, because different types of transformations may be suitable to different models.

For example, when there are sparse or categorical features, the pipelines may matter a lot.